# How to stop ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors from being too active

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, .net-4.5

In my application I am using “validatesonnotifydataerrors” along with “DataAnnotations” so that the user is warned if the field they are editing is empty or has the wrong data etc. The problem I have is that when my view is displayed, all the textboxes are showing warnings because they are empty. What I want to do is only show the warning when the user starts entering incorrect data into that field or if they then delete data and the field becomes empty.

Here is the xaml of one of my TextBoxes:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=AttributeName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=true}" />
```

Here is the backing property:

```
    private string _attributeName;
    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field cannot be blank")]
    public string AttributeName
    {
        get { return _attributeName; }
        set
        {
            _attributeName = value;
            IsDirty = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("AttributeName");
        }
    }
```

Is what I want to do possible with this framework?

Comment: how did you solve your problem? could you please add your solution  because i'm in an similar problem

Answer (score 2):

if you want the the textbox to not to show validation straight away, remove the;

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field cannot be blank")]
```

And then include a RegularExpression instead, like the following;

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,128}$", ErrorMessage = "AttributeName must contain no more then 128 characters and contain no digits.")]
public string AttributeName
{
    get { return _attributeName; }
    set
    {
        _attributeName = value;
        IsDirty = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("AttributeName");
    }
}
```

Then, within the regular expression, you can add or remove certain aspects so that the textbox doesn't allow numbers, symbols etc.

As you notice, You can add a a range of the string to contain, like so `{1,128}` (which takes in from 1 letter up to 128, after that it will appear red on the textbox) so in theory, you wouldn't need to include the `[StringLength(128)]` either.

Take a look at [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat) for more information about Data Annotations/Attribute validation. And also look at [This link also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Doesn’t quite work. If I add text then delete it I don’t get a warning that the field is empty. I’ve verified the regular expression and know that it returns nothing when the field is empty so I would have expected this to trip the warning.

Comment: Well, from your question you wanted the textbox not to contain the validation until the user adds incorrect data, is that correct? So on that basis, having the regular expression should work in theory. Unless I've misread the question :/. It might be to do with your Style otherwise for the validation.

Comment: I have modified my question slightly to make it clearer that by “incorrect” data, that also means an empty field.

Comment: The answer I have provided is half the problem solved. Another suggestion is that you might be able to create a DataTrigger for the `textbox` that way. So when the text has been deleted, hightlight the field.

Comment: I have now fixed the problem. I'll post the solution when I get a free moment. The problem was down to my code calling a ValidateAsync function on every "OnPropertyChanged" event. By fixing this I can now validate on a button click which shows the warning if the field data is too long or empty. Thanks for you quick answer though. Ian